# Need to add parse username to infowindow

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

Is it possible to add a username to a TextView inside an google maps infowindow?

In the following code I am able to get a title, description and image from parse, I want to add the current user to a textview but I have not been able to. What I am looking for is a bit of guidance since there arent many posts in regards to this ( Or perhaps i need to go into the deep web) Her is my code for reference

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.maps_infowindow, null);
                v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) (mapFragment.getView().getMeasuredWidth() * .9), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(marker.getTitle());
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc)).setText(marker.getSnippet());
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user)).setText((CharSequence) ParseUser.getCurrentUser()); // PROBLEM HERE



                Item item = mMarker2Item.get(marker);
                if(item.iconBitmap==null){
                    //this is a blocking call, it will run until download complete
                    item.downloadIcon(getActivity());
                }

                ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
                icon.getLayoutParams().height = 800; // OR
                icon.getLayoutParams().width = 800;

                if(item.iconBitmap!=null){
                    icon.setImageBitmap(item.iconBitmap);
                }else{
                }

                return v;

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh Ok Easy stuff. All I had to do was get the user String from parse and set it to my textView as follows:

```
 String user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("username");
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user)).setText(user);
```